Can't get my OpenZepplin based contract from Remix to verify and publish on etherscan.io
So, I followed a tutorial to make a Token, and the token works fine, but now I am having trouble getting the contract to verify on etherscan.
I think the problem is that the main contract includes libraries that a can't get etherscan to read. Here is my main MyToken.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";

contract MAGAlorian is ERC20, ERC20Permit {
    constructor() ERC20("MAGAlorian", "MAGAL") ERC20Permit("MAGAlorian") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}

I wish the entire code was all in one file. However, it uses a crazy directory structure:
/.deps
./npm
../@openzeppelin
.../contracts
..../interfaces
..../token
..../utils

/contracts/
.MyToken.sol

To make it even more confusing, instead of being in one git repo that I could  maybe send to etherscan.io, the only thing I can seem to do is send top-level items to a "gist". So I can create a gist for /.deps, a gist for contracts/, etc.. but since they aren't in a single top-level folder, I can't get them all in the same gist (I tried using ctrl to highlight them all, but once I do I lose the option to create a gist.
See what I mean: https://gist.github.com/tibberous
I can't make any sense of it. I normally use git repositories, I have no idea how Remix is trying to work using these .gist files.
I am getting ready to launch a "real" token project. Instead of having folders filled with OpenZeppelin files and dependencies, can I move all of the code into a single .sol file?
I don't understand how:
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

Maps it to the path "./deps/npm/@openzepplin";
I didn't worry about it much because:

it was working and

I thought as long as it compiled, the source code wouldn't matter.


I guess other sites want to actually be able to read the source code that compiled into the contract. I thought the idea of Remix being entirely online was really cool, especially since the code I needed was pretty simple. But now it seems like not having the files in folders on my desktop is kind of a liability. If I change the source code after I compile the smart contract there is no way to get the code back and the smart contract is then almost useless. It is like I need to just save the code once deploy the smart contract and then be done with the project. Because the smart contract is immutable, so functionally the code is too.
I basically have two questions:

Is there a way to get this to verify and publish as is on etherscan.io?

Should I have put everything into one *.sol file? Or how would I even go about doing this? I basically used the OpenZeppelin Contract Wizard and changed a couple things. It doesn't give you the option to create a contract as one big file.


I saw a tutorial where a guy basically made his token by taking the published code for another token that was already in one big file (and I think based on openzeppelin's ERC-20) and just pasted it into Remix. It seems like that would be the best way, because anyone who wants to read or audit the code doesn't have to worry about file paths or dependencies -- it's just one file of text you can copy and paste (I doubt anyone would sit down and read it anyway - it is really just to give a copy to etherscan and any other sites that want to verify / audit it.
Thanks for any help.

I ended up using the Etherscan plugin! I can't upvote you because I don't have the reputation on this version of SE,  but thank you so much!
This is the coin we are running with:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xC9Bb222ba7dE0cC203eaeFB683671099171B4c01?a=0x000000fee13a103a10d593b9ae06b3e05f2e7e1c#code
I just got to get the website finished before I send it to eitherscan to get the token info updated, but I verified the source code and verified contract ownership, plus I setup a working pool on uniswap and both be and my partner bought it successfully.
Thanks so much!

To verify a contract having multiple solidity files, that you've created and deployed using Remix IDE, there are two options:

Using Flattener Plugin

Using Etherscan Plugin


The second one would be the easiest as it just requires to get a free Etherscan API key and saving the same on Remix IDE.

Yes! First you need to deploy your contracts onto the blockchain. After that you need to verify that you are the owner of the adress. You can do that either directly on etherscan.io or use and wallet like mycrypto.com with functions like sign messages.
Best would be to get it into one piece if you can. After it's deployed you use the functions sign/verify contracts.
Here is a good guide on how to do it yourself: https://chain.link/tutorials/how-to-verify-a-smart-contract-on-etherscan
